# I have this message: This site doesn't have keywords meta tag!

Tags: seo, meta-keywords

I have this message:

> your site doesn't have keywords meta tag!

What does that means?

Comment: You have just identified an SEO service that **isn't worth the money** they want you to pay them, or a scanner produced by someone who didn't get updated with the reality that the Meta Keyword tag got dropped a decade or more ago as search engine spammers used it to mostly get porn to show up for non-porn searches.

Comment: Where are you seeing that message?

Comment: Big negative, Bing uses Meta Keywords as one of their indicators for SEO spamming. Might want to reconsider having a dead meta tag wasting space on your web page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where do you see this message but for SEO, no worries. The keywords meta tag doesn't take into account anymore by search engines.

You can read [this article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) from Matt Cutts for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Although the keywords are not used by Google, some other search engines may use it. So, it's not a horrible idea to include a keyword meta tag. It won't hurt - assuming they are correctly implemented. And although Google says they don't use it for search rankings, that doesn't mean they don't look at it as a clue to a site that is trying to use it inappropriately.

Comment: Not a good idea, Bing uses Meta Keywords as a spam indicator. One of their online representatives says that it's one of the items taken into consideration in determining that the Bing search bot is being spammed per a direct conversation.